# PHP---why can't I upload image with PHP?

Tags: php, html

The code

```
<?php
    $allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png');
    $max_filesize = 5242888;
    $upload_path = '/files';
    $filename =$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $ext = substr($filename,strpos($filename,'.'),strlen($filename)-1); //Get the     extension form the filename.

    if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
        die('the file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

    if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['size'])>$max_filesize)
        die('the file you attempted to upload is too large.');

    if(!is_writable($upload_path)) {
        die('you cannot upload to the specified directory,please CHMOD it to 777.');
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path.$filename))
    {
        echo 'you file upload successful.view the file <a      href=".$upload_path.$filename.title="your file">here</a>';
    }
    else{
        echo 'failed';
    }
```

When I upload a JPEG image, it shows the error "The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.". What's wrong with my code?

The main HTML code:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="file"/>
    <button>upload</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replace:

```
$ext = substr($filename,strpos($filename,'.'),strlen($filename)-1); 
//get the  extension form the filename
```

by

```
$ext = substr($filename,strpos($filename,'.'),4);
//get the     extension form the filename
```

Comment: You should check $ext by print it out, so we are sure that it's in 
$allowed_filetypes

Comment: i changed strlen($filename)-1 to 3, but it still shows the error.

Comment: you're right, when i echo the $ext, it shows the 'the file you attempted to upload is not allowed. what's wrong with my code. thank you

Comment: i'm sorry, the actual value must be 4, not 3, because your file type include 4 character (.jpg for instance).

Comment: and you use "die", so it always stop and only show your "die message". You can try logging by : http://www.redips.net/php/write-to-log-file/

Comment: Replace your $ext line by this code, it will fix the problem: $ext = substr($filename,strpos($filename,'.'),strlen($filename)-4);

Answer (score 2):

Please use in form tag

```
 <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: then you are adding image extension not in array then change array as array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png', .JPG','.GIF','.BMP','.PNG'); and echo $ext varriable and check

Answer (score 0):

Try with a submit button, <input type="submit " name="upload" value="upload"/>.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="file"/>
    <input type="submit" name="sendFile" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

that should work.